# Connection string for local database not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net, connection-string

I have a database on my local machine on SQL Server Management studio. 
[image: SQL Server Management Studio]

The database connection information is as follows.
[image: DB info]

In my c# application, I have a connection string to connect to this database. I get an error though saying my connection string is incorrect. I have tried a number of different ones.

This is my function to connect to a database.

```
  public virtual void openConnection()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-8UDMQUI\\WILLIAMSQL;Initial Catalog=team3db;TrustServerCertificate=true;";

        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

I have two \ in the server name because when I only have one, it has a red squiggle line under it throwing me an error on visual studio.

What should my connection string be? Note there is no password on this database.

Comment: If you want to use windows authentication in your conString. Then use `con.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-8UDMQUI\\WILLIAMSQL;Initial Catalog=team3db;TrustedConnection=true;";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `TrustServerCertificate = true;` with `Integrated Security = true`

Comment: The TrustServerCertificate keyword is valid only when connecting to a SQL Server instance with a valid certificate.